# Do packets routed to another interface using `pf`'s `route-to` option on macOS actually pass the given interface?

Tags: network, mojave, firewall

> Do packets routed to another interface using `pf`'s `route-to` option on macOS actually pass the given interface?

I've read that `pf`'s firewall rules only applies to packets that (physically) pass the given interface. Thus, rules for a gateway's external interface will not apply to packets entering on the local interface and destined for the external interface, since the TCP/IP stack handles such packets internally.

Thus, do packets that are `route-to` (filter rule) another interface on the gateway pass that interface, so that the interface's rules will apply to the packet?

Here is the documentation from the OSX man page:

```
 route-to
       The route-to option routes the packet to the specified interface with an optional address for the next hop.  When a route-to rule creates state, only packets that pass in the same direction as the filter
       rule specifies will be routed in this way.  Packets passing in the opposite direction (replies) are not affected and are routed normally.
```

Comment: The best way for you to verify this is to use a packet browser on your connections/interfaces.

Comment: I've verified that rules apply, but does the reference say that? Maybe a high-skilled firewall guy can answer that.

Comment: You could answer it by yourself if you would sniff what passes on the wire. A little hint on a packet-tracer app: Wireshark (is the world’s foremost and widely-used network protocol analyzer)

Answer (score 1):

> I've read that pf's firewall rules only applies to packets that (physically) pass the given interface.

I remember [answering](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/538790/6622) to your similar question on unix.stackexchange.com

> Thus, rules for a gateway's external interface will not apply to packets entering on the local interface and destined for the external interface, since the TCP/IP stack handles such packets internally.

Pf's rules *do apply to traffic over loopback too* unless you're specifically exclude it with smth like `set skip on lo0`.

You also better keep in mind that [Pf's version shipped with MacOS is severely outdated](https://etcinsider.com/blog/2016/02/28/openbsd-pf-for-mac-os-x-is-mostly-outdated/) and some documented features of Pf don't work at all or work incorrectly. `route-to` is somewhat "hacky" feature and I won't be any surprised if it'd fail in similar ways.